# can't delete azure hdinsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have attempted to delete a hadoop cluster, but in the notifications section of the dashboard I still see this after about 8 hours:

[image]

How can I delete my cluster?

I'm using the free trial of azure which has redirected me here for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We investigated this issue and found out that the delete request somehow couldn't make it to the back end. Can you please reload the portal and try again?

Sorry for the inconvenience! Please send me a note at [adnan dot ijaz at microsoft dot com] so that I can help with you the refund.

--Adnan (on behalf of HDInsight Engineering)

Comment: We are also experiencing the same issue. The HDI blade in portal shows Deleting for hours. Refresh and someone else logging to portal sees the same status. The issue started from Last Friday (29Jun2018), on that day one cluster deleted by taking very long time, (some time during weekend it deleted)

Comment: After 12 Hours of waiting, I tried to delete the same cluster using PowerShell from portal.It returned error but the portal flashed and automatically closed the HDI instance blade. When I opened the HDI Clusters page the cluster is not there.

Comment: More updates May be helpful to some one. The HDICluster deletion via PowerShell was not complete. It left some infrastructure components orphaned such as public IP...There seems something going on badly.